# Having problem in installing composer in php

Tags: php, xampp, xa

I am getting this all errors while installing composer:

```
# php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
PHP Warning:  Failed loading Zend extension 'ΓÇ£D:\xampp\php\ioncube\ioncube_loader_win_5.3.dllΓÇ¥' (tried: D:\xampp\php\ext\ΓÇ£D:\xampp\php\ioncube\ioncube_loader_win_5.3.dllΓÇ¥
(The specified module could not be found.), D:\xampp\php\ext\php_ΓÇ£D:\xampp\php\ioncube\ioncube_loader_win_5.3.dllΓÇ¥.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown o
n line 0

Warning: Failed loading Zend extension 'ΓÇ£D:\xampp\php\ioncube\ioncube_loader_win_5.3.dllΓÇ¥' (tried: D:\xampp\php\ext\ΓÇ£D:\xampp\php\ioncube\ioncube_loader_win_5.3.dllΓÇ¥ (The
specified module could not be found.), D:\xampp\php\ext\php_ΓÇ£D:\xampp\php\ioncube\ioncube_loader_win_5.3.dllΓÇ¥.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on lin
e 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'curl' already loaded in Unknown on line 0

Warning: Module 'curl' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
```

Please Help!

Comment: you need to install the ionCube PHP extension. for this here is the link you can follow - https://www.gurock.com/testrail/docs/admin/howto/installing-ioncube